# How to avoid duplicate record on pagination in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, pagination

I have done pagination in php. but after certain record it display duplicate entry from certain rows.

My query is when loading page first time is

`select * from sakhe WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY sakhe_id ASC limit 0,30`

My query on second time when scrolling (It executed twice on one scrolling )

`select * from sakhe WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY sakhe_id ASC limit 30,30`

after this query I found correct data in console. but it display duplicate on site.

My Js code like this

```
var page = 1;
var total_page = "";

function getresult(searches) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "process/Sakhe_list.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            Sakhe_name: $("#Sakhe_name").val(),
            page: page
        },

        success: function (data) {
            if (searches == true) {


                $("#rows").html(data);
            } else {
                $("#rows").append(data);
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    getresult(false);

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 5) {

            if ($(".current_page:last").val() <= $("#total_page").val()) {
                page = parseInt($(".current_page:last").val()) + 1;
                getresult(false);
            }
        }
    });


    $("#shopsubmit").click(function () {
        page = 1;
        getresult(true);
    });

    $("#reset").click(function () {
        $("#Sakhe_name").val("");


        page = 1;
        getresult(true);
    });
```

My PHP code is this

```
extract($_REQUEST);

$perPage = 30; // total records per page
// page
$conditionArr = array(); // array for condition
$condition = ""; // conditions

$pages = ""; // how many pages created
$type = "";
$company = "";
$message = "";

$rersArr = array();
$data = array();
$templeArr = array();


if ($Sakhe_name != "") {
    array_push($conditionArr, "name LIKE '%" . $Sakhe_name . "%'");
}
$sql = "select * from sakhe WHERE status = 1 ";

if (sizeOf($conditionArr) > 0) {
    $condition = implode(" AND ", $conditionArr);
//    echo $condition;
    $sql .= " AND $condition";
}

$start = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
$sql1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);
$pages = ceil($count / $perPage);
$sql .= " ORDER BY sakhe_id ASC";
$sql .= " limit $start,$perPage ";
print_r("final ".$sql);
?>

    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="5">
            <input type="hidden" name="total_page" id="total_page" value="<?php echo $pages; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="current_page" class="current_page" id="current_page"
                   value="<?php echo $page; ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Currently I am getting last 7 duplicate record.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: use `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: I am using MySql @jarlh

Comment: Pagination tip: https://www.slideshare.net/Eweaver/efficient-pagination-using-mysql

Comment: there is an issue while your `append` data in HTML. is this condition working `searches == true` ?

Comment: I am getting correct record from data base and no record is duplicate in database. @KUMAR

Comment: No. ``searches == true `` is not working. I recent found @Gulshan

Comment: @MeetPatel that's every time data is `append` in HTML. Fix it. It will work fine. Simple remove condition and use `$("#rows").html(data);`

Comment: It works fine. but after that if I scroll. other query executed that take no data. so it results blank page . @Gulshan

Comment: @MeetPatel put a condition on `success`,   `if(data.length > 0) { $("#rows").html(data); }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199834/discussion-between-meet-patel-and-gulshan).

Comment: ohh !! yes I should use prepared statement. @Dharman

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your `searches == true` condition. that's every time data is appended in HTML. Fix it. It will work fine. Simple remove condition
and use below code:

```
if(data !== 'undefined' && data !== '') { 
 $("#rows").html(data); 
}
```

Comment: After last scroll all data magically disappear. I check it because of it execute query that result NO data. But query should not executed on scroll.

Comment: still it disappear from screen on last scroll. @Gulshan

Comment: can you put your `console.log(data)` here while last scroll?

Comment: Here is   ``console.log(data)``   `<tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="5">
            <input type="hidden" name="total_page" id="total_page" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="current_page" class="current_page" id="current_page"
                   value="3">
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr><td colspan="12">No records found</td></tr>  `

Comment: put a condition on server-side, if `result` is empty, don't `return` anything.

Answer (score 0):

If it shows Duplicated Data then it can be fixed from query using DISTINCT keyword

```
select DISTINCT from sakhe WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY sakhe_id ASC limit 0,30
```

and:

```
select DISTINCT from sakhe WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY sakhe_id ASC limit 30,30
```